# K not working in command in visual mode

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to do the following mapping to open the correct help topic underneath my cursor:

```
nnoremap K viWlF=hK
```

This works for the first term:

- `belloff=all`

But not for the second:

- `splitbelow`

For the second, it just highlights the word correctly, but doesn't open the help section. If I manually press `K` on my keyboard, it will then open the help section but doesn't do so automatically. Why is this occurring, and how could I fix this? Note that if I manually type in `viWlF=hK` it works for both.

This allows me to open something more easily like:

- `'viminfo'`
- `c_CTRL-R`

For whatever reason, putting it into a function worked:

```
function MyFunc() abort
    normal! viWlF=h
    normal! K
endfunction
nnoremap K :call MyFunc()
```

Comment: Why do you want to remap 'K' at all? It's enough to move cursor on 'belloff' (not "all") and it just works.

Comment: @Matt sure, but if you do the same on `'viminfo'` it opens `:h viminfo` instead of `h: 'viminfo'`, same with ctrl-r

Comment: By fixing one error you will most likely do another one. E.g. press "remapped" K on `exists("g:syntax_on")` and you won't get to `:h g:syntax_on` anymore. Just do it normal way and manually use Visual mode when it's really needed. Trying to be too smart rarely pays off.

Comment: @Matt -- agreed, I ended up doing this which uses the default unless I manually put the help word between `*`'s (I'm surprised vim doesn't do that by default when pressing K, or is there an option for that too?) https://imgur.com/a/6KR1biO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mapping is interrupted if a command fails. For example, `l` would fail if your `splitbelow` is at the end of a line, and if it wasn't then the `F=` would fail if there was no `=` on that line.

This behavior is documented under [`:help map-error`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-error):

> Note that when an error is encountered (that causes an error message or beep)
>   the rest of the mapping is not executed.  This is Vi-compatible.

Comment: I see. So in the above case, I should remove the `abort` from my function? I disabled all beeping, etc. so am not too sure when something actually 'fails' or just nothing happens.

Comment: @David542 This is about a mapping, not a function... The `abort` on the function is unrelated.

Comment: I see. Then for the above mapping (or function), what/how would you suggest doing it?

Comment: @David542 I actually suggest not using a map at all, just use `viWK` when you need it for something that includes non-keyword characters.

Comment: one last question -- if it errors, why don't the function stop if there's an `abort`. Why does it run all the way through? By this I mean the function at the end of my question.

Comment: @David542 Failure of an Ex command (which would fail a function tagged with "abort") is different from failure of a Normal mode command (which is the one that interrupts a mapping.) Running a `:normal!` with a sequence including a Normal mode command that fails will not produce an Ex command failure of the `:normal!` command. Hopefully that's a little bit clearer...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification -- though that error behavior is a bit strange!